# What are the least amount of pairs that need to be added for R to be transitive?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let R be the following relation on the set $S = \begin{Bmatrix}
w,x,y,z
\end{Bmatrix}$

$R = \begin{Bmatrix}
(w,w),(w,y),(x,w),(x,x),(y,w),(y,z),(z,w)
\end{Bmatrix}$

The relation R is not transitive. What are the least amount of pairs that need to be added for R to be transitive?

**My answer:**

(y,y) (x,y) (w,z)

**Correct answer:**

(y,y) (x,y) **(x,z)**

**Question:**

I don't understand that "correct answer". Could it be wrong? For (x,z) to be added the set needs to have the elements (x,?) and (?,z). Could that answer be wrong and my answer right?

Comment: It seems that your answer is the correct one.

Comment: If you add $(w,z)$, havin already $(z,w)$, you have to add $(z,z)$ also.

Comment: Adding $(x,y)$, we need also and $(x,z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your answer and the supposed "correct answer" are both incorrect.

A relation is defined to be transitive when for any $a,b,c$ (*possibly repeated values*) you have that if $(a,b)$ is in the relation and so too is $(b,c)$ then $(a,c)$ is also needed in the relation.

Something that many beginning students fail to recognize is that although this is phrased in terms of only three variables... it directly implies a similar statement about an arbitrary number of variables.

An equivalent statement (*make sure you fully understand why*):  A relation is transitive iff for any $\alpha$ (*representing beginning*) and $\omega$ (*representing end*) and **any** number of elements $m_1,m_2,m_3,\dots,m_k$ (*with possibly repeated values*), if you have each of $(\alpha,m_1),(m_1,m_2),(m_2,m_3),\dots,(m_k,\omega)$ in the relation, then so too must you have $(\alpha,\omega)$ in the relation.

Reworded in more plain of English... if you think of each element as a "place" and each pair in the relation as saying "I can get from this place to this other place" then to be transitive means that *if you can get from one place to another* **using any number** of inbetween stops (*not just two*), then so too must you have a shortcut so that you can get from your start to your destination in a single step.

---

As you were making your attempt you were ignoring the fact that chains of *any* length, not just of length $2$, must have a direct path from the start to the end included in the relation and you also were ignoring that chains where elements are *repeated* must also be considered.

Starting with $\{(w,w),(w,y),(x,w),(x,x),(y,w),(y,z),(z,w)\}$, since you have $(x,w),(w,y),(y,z),(z,w),(w,y),(y,z)$ you must add each of $(w,z),(y,y),(z,z),(y,w)$ and you must also add $(x,y),(x,z)$ to have transitive closure.

Comment: Ok thanks I think I understand what you mean. So (,),(,),(,),(,)  (,),(,) is your answer? Don't you think that maybe there's a shorter answer since the question specifically states "the least amount of pairs needed"

Comment: If i understand you right the "correct answer" makes more sense. We finally add  (x,z) to "close" the added (x,y). And here is the end because (,) is already in the set. Needed to end (,)

Comment: So in other words you need to watch-out every time a pair is added to the list to make sure that no new pairs are needed. Thanks good explanation :)

Comment: @DanielAndersson the "correct answer" that was listed in your post is as mentioned incorrect since it does not for instance include $(w,z)$ despite both $(w,y)$ and $(y,z)$ being elements of the relation.  Further it does not include $(w,w)$ since each of $(w,y),(y,z),(z,w)$ are included in the relation.  I could go on.  Since you have $(w,y),(y,z),(z,w)$ by continuing in this fashion, you see that each of $w,y,z$ can all get to any of $w,y,z$ and so these three form a "complete (including loops) subgraph" of the relation.  All six I listed are necessary, not just three.