# Is this relation a transitive one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

$$A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$$

Is the relation `x > y` on $A$ transitive?

If yes please explain why it is so.

There will be the pair `(2,1)` as 2 > 1. However `y` being 1 will have no other pair (y,z) as 1 is the smallest number in the set $A$. So the condition
for the relation to be transitive:

$\forall x,y,z \in A : x R y \land y R z \implies x R z$.

will return false as there will be no $y R z$ pair to satisfy the whole condition.

Is my thinking right?

Comment: As an aside, I suspect that if you made this mistake with transitivity then you are likely going to make another very common mistake with transitivity.  I recommend checking out the question and my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3251697/what-are-the-least-amount-of-pairs-that-need-to-be-added-for-r-to-be-transitive/) about the transitive closure of a relation and remind you that transitivity doesn't just refer to three elements at a time, but rather to *any number*, i.e. if $a_1Ra_2$ and $a_2Ra_3$ and ... and $a_{n-1}Ra_n$ then if transitive  you have $a_1Ra_n$.

Comment: It is also worth reminding that for these elements, they do not need to be distinct.  The relation $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is not transitive for instance as you could take $x=z=1$ and $y=2$ to see you have $1R2$ and $2R1$ but you don't have $1R1$.

Comment: @JMoravitz ye I think I get it. In your example to this relation be transitive it should contain a pair (1,1), am I right?

Comment: as well as $(2,2)$.  The transitive closure of $\{(1,2),(2,1)\}$ is $\{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$.

Comment: I don't get it why it need to include (2,2). The transitivity relation doesn't regard the third pair being (x,z)? May you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Because $(2,1)$ and $(1,2)$ are in the relation, letting $x=z=2$ and $y=1$ you would have that $(x,y)$ is in the relation and $(y,z)$ is in the relation, so for it to be transitive you would need $(x,z)$ in the relation as well.

Comment: Oh now I got it. After including (1,1) and the relation being {(1,2),(2,1),(1,1)} when testing the transitivity of pair (2,1) it will endup catching (1,2) as (y,z) thus requiring the pair (2,2) to be included in the relation to it be transitive. Did I really got it right now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you have universal quantification. If you have pair $(x, y)$ in relation, you don't necessary need to have a pair $(y, z)$ also in relation - you just need *if there is such pair* to also have $(x, z)$ in relation.

The transitivity condition requires you to have pair $(x, z)$ only if there already are pairs $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$. It doesn't require anything about $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$.

And this relation is transitive. You can see it by either writing all $6$ of its elements directly, or by noting that it's just restriction of usual transitive order on integer numbers to set $A$.

Comment: Very well explained, thanks. So any of these conditions applied to a relation on any set of integers will be transitive: `<`, `<=`, `=`, `>` and `>=`?

Comment: Yes, correct. This relations are themselves transitive, and restriction of transitive relation to a subset is transitive.

Answer (score 3):

Its transitive. The relation $>$ is defined on the natural numbers as $x>y$ if there a natural number $a>0$ such that $x=y+a$.

Thus if $x>y$ and $y>z$, then there are $a,b>0$ such that $x=y+a$ and $y=z+b$. Therefore,
$x=z+(a+b)$ with $a+b>0$. Hence, $x>z$.

As another question of the OP (see comments) if a relation is transitive, its inverse relation is also transitive. Inverse of $>$ is $<$ and inverse of $\geq$ is $\leq$.

The relation $\geq$ is also transitive. Its definition: $x\geq y$ iff there is a natural number $a\geq 0$ such that $x=a+y$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Could we confirm then that any relation where x`<`, `<=`, `=`, `>` or `>=` y will be transitive?

Comment: See my comment please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the relation is transitive since you are considering (a,b) pair it's not necessary that there should be pair (b,c) "if" there is a pair (b,c) then (a,c) should be in the set.